# Using Querystring and ASP.NET AJAX successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Good day to all of you.

I am using a FormView in ASP.NET application (VS 2010 SP1), and this FormView incorporates two functions: Insert and Update.
The FormView uses only 1 template: EditItemTemplate in order to achieve the aforementioned functionalities.

When Inserting a new record, the generated ID is returned by the ObjectDataSource, and is used as a querystring to be appended to the current URL, and then is used by the datasource to select the newly inserted record for editing. The FormView is surrounded by an update panel to utilize AJAX technology.

*The ASPX code is:*

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:FormView ID="fvw_MoFA_NGOs_List" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id"
        DataSourceID="ods_MoFA_List" OnInit="fvw_MoFA_NGOs_List_Init" 
        OnItemCommand="fvw_MoFA_NGOs_List_ItemCommand" DefaultMode="Edit"
        Width="98%">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <table style="width: 50%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        id:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="idLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Arabic Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Ar_NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ar_Name") %>' />                                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vld_ArNm" ControlToValidate="Ar_NameTextBox" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="Arabic name is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        English Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="En_NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("En_Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vld_EnNm" ControlToValidate="En_NameTextBox" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="English name is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Governorate of Headquarters:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Hq_Governorate") %>'
                            DataSourceID="ods_Governorates" DataTextField="Mohafaza_EN" DataValueField="Mohafaza_pcode_PK">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <br />
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
                            Text="Insert" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Update" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                            Text="Cancel" Visible="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</ContentTemplate>
```

The associated ObjectDataSource is (note the **SelectParameters**):

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods_MoFA_List" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert_Get_NwId"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" OnInserted="ods_MoFA_List_Inserted"
        SelectMethod="GetDataById" TypeName="NGOs_IIMS.NGOs_Module_IIMS.DAL.NGOs_IIMSTableAdapters.NGOs_MoFA_NGOs_ListsTableAdapter"
        UpdateMethod="Update" OnInserting="ods_MoFA_List_Inserting" OnUpdating="ods_MoFA_List_Updating">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Ar_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="En_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Rdate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Creator" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Hq_Governorate" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="-1" Name="pid" QueryStringField="MoFAid"
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Ar_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="En_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Rdate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Creator" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Hq_Governorate" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

*And the querystring appending is done when the new record is inserted:*

```
protected void ods_MoFA_List_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ReturnValue != null)
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?" + New_MoFA_NGO + "=" + e.ReturnValue.ToString());   
}
```

**The problem is:**

When inserting, the whole page is refreshed despite AJAX, but when updating the inserted record AJAX works correctly.

**Is there something wrong in using the querystring with AJAX? should I depend on the Session variables here even though they are not the best choice?**

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
      //Your Html code 
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This will prevent refreshing the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to the UpdatePanel:
`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">`
alas, the page is still refreshing.